# dash reports 'Syntax error: "(" unexpected' when using process substitution

Tags: bash, dash

I have following bash command

```
diff <(xzcat file1.xz) <(xzcat file2.xz)
```

and I need to execute it in `dash`. On my system (Debian Wheezy), `dash` is the default interpreter for cron (`/bin/sh` is a link to `/bin/dash`).

When I execute the command in `dash`, I get following error:

```
Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism

Comment: Debian also has a checkbashisms script. I forget the package name, though.

Comment: The package name is `devscripts`

Comment: See also: ['-sh: syntax error: unexpected "("' when attempting process substitution on an embedded Linux device with `bash`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/676681/114401)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, process substitution is a non-standard feature originated in ksh and only available in ksh, bash and zsh.

On systems that support `/dev/fd/n` (like Debian), you can do:

```
xzcat < file1.xz | { xzcat < file2.xz | diff /dev/fd/3 -; } 3<&0
```

Or you can always do:

```
bash -c 'diff <(xzcat file1.xz) <(xzcat file2.xz)'
```

Answer (score 7):

If you need a specific shell when running something from a cron job wrap it in a script and call the script from the cron.

```
#!/bin/bash

diff <(xzcat file1.xz) <(xzcat file2.xz)
```

#### Cron entry

```
*  *  *  *  * user-name  /path/to/above/script.bash
```

Answer (score 4):

If you must use `dash`, this will work:

```
mkfifo file1
mkfifo file2
xzcat file1.xz >file1&
xzcat file2.xz >file2&
diff file1 file2
rm -f file1 file2 #remove the FIFOs
```

Comment: That's a can of worm though as you have to make sure only one instance is run at a time and that the fifos are not readable by anybody, and that they are properly created and destroyed...

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Agreed. Thanks for pointing this out.