# '-sh: syntax error: unexpected "("' when attempting process substitution on an embedded Linux device with `bash`

Tags: bash, shell, process-substitution

This uses ["process substitution"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2443120/4561887) (`<()`) and a ["heredoc"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697688/how-to-cat-eof-a-file-containing-code) (`cat << EOF...EOF`) to open a new bash process where it runs the startup "file" (`--rcfile`) containing `alias foo="echo hey you`. Here is the command:

```bsh
bash --rcfile <(
cat << EOF
alias foo="echo hey you"
EOF
)
```

It works on Ubuntu just fine, as you can see here:

```bsh
$ bash --rcfile <(
> cat << EOF
> alias foo="echo hey you"
> EOF
> )
$ foo
hey you
$ alias
alias foo='echo hey you'
```

**However, when I try to run this on certain embedded Linux devices, I get the following error. Why? How do I make it run there too?**

> ```
> -sh: syntax error: unexpected "("
> ```

Full output:

> ```
> $ bash --rcfile <(
> -sh: syntax error: unexpected "("
> $ cat << EOF
> > alias foo="echo hey you"
> > EOF
> alias foo="echo hey you"
> $ )
> -sh: syntax error: unexpected ")"
> ```

In case this helps, here are my `which bash` and `bash --version` outputs on Ubuntu vs the embedded Linux device:

```bsh
# 1. Ubuntu

$ which bash
/bin/bash
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.


# 2. Embedded Linux device

$ which bash
/bin/bash
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.16(1)-release (aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

### Not a duplicate:

This is related but does *not* seem to be a duplicate: [dash reports 'Syntax error: "(" unexpected' when using process substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93290/dash-reports-syntax-error-unexpected-when-using-process-substitution).

### Related:

1. [my own question] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69891328/what-is-the-syntax-in-shell-bash-and-how-do-i-search-for-it

### Notes to self

My end-goal is to automatically create some custom aliases when I ssh in, like this perhaps:

```bsh
ssh -t username@ip_address '/bin/bash --rcfile <(
cat << EOF
alias foo="echo hey you"
EOF
)'
```

Update: done! Here is what I came up with:

```bsh
# Store your password into a file
echo "my_password" > ~/pw

# Manually add something like this to your ~/.bash_aliases (recommended) or ~/.bashrc file on the PC
# you are ssh-ing FROM:
alias gs_ssh="sshpass -f ~/pw scp /etc/skel/.bashrc root@192.168.0.2:/tmp \
&& sshpass -f ~/pw ssh -t -o 'ServerAliveInterval 60' root@192.168.0.2 'bash --rcfile /tmp/.bashrc'"
```

See my repo here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master/home/.ssh#optional-but-recommended-alias.

Comment: You have a device with bash, sure, but are you running this command in bash?

Comment: @muru, I'm typing `bash --rcfile...`, so it is running it in `bash` right there, no? The `--rcfile` part and everything thereafter are the parameters to the `bash` cmd.

Comment: Depends on what shell you're typing `bash --rcfile` into. That's the one that interprets the `<(...)`

Comment: @muru: aaaah; that makes sense! That's running in `sh` I think. So, first I must run `bash` and THEN I can run that next cmd with the process substitution.

Comment: @muru, okay: manually running `bash` first allows me to then run the cmd fine on the Linux device. BUT, I cannot seem to script the two cmds together as the first shell is what always interprets both of them. So, I'm still stuck.

Comment: Note: running [`echo $0`](https://askubuntu.com/a/590902/327339) on the embedded Linux device shows `-sh`, meaning it is running `sh` by default when I first log in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the embedded Linux devices support `/dev/fd/` entries? If they do, try passing the initialization commands over file descriptor #3, like this:

```
bash --rcfile /dev/fd/3 3<<EOF
alias foo="echo hey you"
exec 3<&-
EOF
```

EDIT: Stéphane Chazelas suggested adding `exec 3<&-` as the final command in the "script"; this closes the file descriptor, so it's not left dangling for the entire shell session.

Comment: Yes, that works! `ls /dev/fd` shows: `0  1  2  3  4`. What does all these mean? Why did you choose `3` instead of one of the other four options? See also my follow-up question here: [What does the output of `ll /proc/self/fd/` (from `ll /dev/fd`) mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/676683/what-does-the-output-of-ll-proc-self-fd-from-ll-dev-fd-mean)

Comment: Note to self: see also: [What is the portable (POSIX) way to achieve process substitution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309594/114401)

Comment: @GabrielStaples File descriptors #0 through #2 are already in use (#0 is standard input, #1 is standard output, #2 is standard error), but #3 is almost always available for random other uses.

Comment: That makes sense; thank you very much. I'm beginning to make better sense of Linux. When we open a new file with [`open()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), and it returns a file descriptor integer to us, does that mean `/dev/fd` will now show another file descriptor integer greater than `4`?

Comment: @GabrielStaples I think so, but I'm not fully familiar with the details (and it may depend on the OS).

Comment: You could also add a `exec 3<&-` at the end of that heredoc for the tempfile or pipe used for the here doc to be released after bash has read it.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not the syntax of your command is supported or not is determined by whatever shell you are currently running.

Your current shell is `sh` when you try to execute your `bash --rcfile <(...)` command, which is evident from the error message where the shell identifies itself as a `sh` shell running as a login shell.   This shell does not generally understand process substitutions.

One way to work around this is to first `exec bash`, which is replacing the current shell with a shell that understands process substitutions, or to do [as is suggested by Gordon Davisson](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/676681/493832) and provide the temporary initialization file via an alternative file descriptor.

```bsh
exec bash

bash --rcfile <( cat <<'BASHRC'
alias foo='echo bumblebee'
BASHRC
)
```

```bsh
bash --rcfile /dev/fd/3 3<<'BASHRC'
alias foo='echo bumblebee'
exec 3<&-
BASHRC
```

Note that you, in either case, most likely want to quote the here-document, unless you need the current shell to carry out expansions in the document before the new `bash` shell reads it.  You may also want to use `exec bash` if replacing the current shell completely is what you want to do.

Comment: Ideally, the first example would work as a single command, but it does not. Rather, `exec bash` (or just `bash`) must be run first, and then after running that I can copy/paste the next part of the command and it works with process substitution. It looks like I cannot script the whole thing as a single command while having the `bash` part run first.

Comment: How is `exec bash` different from `bash` anyway? Both seem to work the same in testing.

Comment: @GabrielStaples If you give the command `bash`, you start a `bash` shell session.  If you then say `exit` in that session, you get back to the initial shell.  With `exec bash`, you _replace_ the current shell with a `bash` shell session, which means that if you type `exit`, you terminate that terminal session completely (or log out, if were logged in via a text console or SSH).

Comment: Ahhh, I actually noticed that when I typed `exit` a few minutes ago but didn't understand the new and "aberrant" behavior, nor why it happened!